# HTACCESS Help Directories and Files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am not familiar with the field at all, it's quite confusing.

- Block anything outside of root from being accessed (/ = OKAY /outside/ = BAD)
- Files cannot be accessed directly however they can be included (PHP)

I am not sure where to start but it's important that users can not access directories outside of the root folder, this only allows them to open index.php which will include the rest.

The problem I seem to have is not knowing what to search for, any help would be great. :)

Comment: You can password-protect subdirectories. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to prevent folders outside of root to be accessed, as well with the files it contains. Though with that being like so, I want the files to be able to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deny all requests for the restricted directory, prepare a .htaccess file for each directory and put the following directive in it:

deny from all